# Can I consolidate all deposited ether to one wallet address without additional transactions?

Tags: java, ethereum, web3-java

I am making an application in which I am creating a different Ethereum wallet address for a user in the Ethereum blockchain using web3J.

I have also created one address say as my organisation wallet. When a user deposits some ether in their respective address, I want all the ether to be deposited into my organisation wallet. What I understand that to do this I have to do an another transaction from user account to organisation wallet, which leads to the deduction of transaction fee from user account and not all the ether will go to organisation wallet.

Is there any another approach to do this?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any another approach to do this?

No.

That is what blockchain transactions are all about.

Comment: but if we use bitcoin blockchain,we can create multiple addresess of a one wallet,and all balance will consolidate into same wallet. But in ethereum there is seperate account address. So i am not able to consolidate all balance into one account.